# Proof that group is commutative if every element is its inverse (feedback wanted)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, soft-question, proof-verification, proof-writing

This is one of my first proofs about groups. Please feed back and criticise in every way (including style & language).
Axiom names ([see Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Definition)) are *italicised*. $e$ denotes the identity element.

---

Let $(G, \cdot)$ be a group.
We assume that every element is its inverse.
It remains to prove that our group is commutative.
Non-trivially, $\textit{associativity}$ implies that parentheses are unnecessary.
Therefore, we do not use parentheses,
we will not use $\textit{associativity}$ explicitly.

By $\textit{identity element}$, $G \ne \emptyset$.
Now, let $a, b \in G$.
By assumption, $$aa = e \text{ and } bb = e. \quad \text{(I)}$$
By $\textit{closure}$, $ab \in G$.
So, by assumption, $$abab = e.\quad \text{(II)}$$
It remains to prove that $ab = ba$.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
ab &= aeb && \quad\text{by }\textit{identity element} \\
   &= aababb && \quad\text{by (II)} \\
   &= ebabb && \quad\text{by (I)} \\
   &= ebae && \quad\text{by (I)} \\
   &= bae && \quad\text{by }\textit{identity element} \\
   &= ba && \quad\text{by }\textit{identity element}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
QED

Comment: Seems fine to me :)

Comment: good attempt !!!

Comment: It is fine. You may show is using reversal rule also. $$ab=(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}=ba$$

Comment: Is "non-trivially" a common word + used correctly?

Comment: @LaxmikantMishra: D'oh. I was at $abba = aea = aa = e$, therefore $ba = (ab)^{-1} = ab$, but yours is better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is correct, however, you might see the way similarly as: $$a(ab)b=a^2b^2=e=(ab)^2=a(ba)b.$$