# Group Property of element

Tags: abstract-algebra

True or false? If $G$ is a group with the property that $g=g^{-1}$
 for all g element  $G$, then $G$ is abelian .prove

true ,inverse exits which is in G,for it to be abelian ,it means that it is commutative that is $ab=ba$

Comment: so i am right the answer is true

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910640/proof-that-group-is-commutative-if-every-element-is-its-inverse-feedback-wanted).

Comment: Please try the search first next time. There are already a handful of posts on this question.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a,b\in G$ then

$$ab=(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}=ba$$
and we conclude.